# Ambiguity in Low priority implicits

Tags: scala, scala-implicits

I have the following snippet of Scala code:

```
  import java.io.PrintWriter

  trait Write[-A] {
    def apply(out: PrintWriter)(x: A): Unit
  }

  trait LowPriorityWrites {
    implicit object any extends Write[Any] {
      override def apply(out: PrintWriter)(x: Any) = out.print(x)
    }
  }

  object Write extends LowPriorityWrites {
    implicit def iterable[A](implicit write: Write[A]): Write[Traversable[A]] = new Write[Traversable[A]] {
      override def apply(out: PrintWriter)(xs: Traversable[A]) = {
        xs foreach write(out)
        out.println()
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is that first look for an implicit in `Write` object. If not, fall back to the default `.toString` for `Any` from `LowPriorityWrites`.

But, this approach does not work:

```
ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both method iterable in object Write of type [A](implicit write: Write[A])Write[Traversable[A]]
[error]  and object any in trait LowPriorityWrites of type Write.any.type
[error]  match expected type Write[Seq[Long]]
```

Comment: Can't write a full answer at the moment, but if you make the fallback instance generic the priorities will work out just fine.

Comment: Yup replacing `Any` with `A` worked. Thanks!

Comment: @TravisBrown: When you have a moment, write up an answer and I will accept it. It would be nice to know WHY `Any` does not work. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed wholeheartedly!

Comment: Reasons are similar to those in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933865/why-is-this-implicit-ambiguity-behaviour-happening/