# Why is this implicit ambiguity behaviour happening?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, ambiguous, type-level-computation

I have a typeclass `Search`, which has an instance `Search[A]` if we have a `TypeClass1[A]` or a `TypeClass2[A]` instance. With preference given to the `1` instance.

The following compiles:

```scala
trait TypeClass1[A]
trait TypeClass2[A]
trait Search[A]

object Search extends LPSearch {
  implicit def case1[A](implicit ev: TypeClass1[A]): Search[A] = null
}

trait LPSearch {
  implicit def case2[A](implicit ev: TypeClass2[A]): Search[A] = null
}

object Test {
  implicit val ev1: TypeClass1[Int] = null
  implicit val ev2: TypeClass2[Int] = null
  implicitly[Search[Int]]
}
```

This is as I would expect, the implicit search finds `case1`, finds `ev1`, and stops searching.

However, if we change `TypeClass2` to have more structure, the implicit search stops working:

```scala
trait TypeClass1[A]
trait TypeClass2[M[_], A]
trait Search[A]

object Search extends LPSearch {
  // This is the same as before
  implicit def case1[A](implicit ev: TypeClass1[A]): Search[A] = null
}

trait LPSearch {
  implicit def case2[M[_], A](implicit ev: TypeClass2[M, A]): Search[M[A]] = null
}

object Test {
  implicit val ev1: TypeClass1[List[Int]] = null
  implicit val ev2: TypeClass2[List, Int] = null

  // Does not compile:
  implicitly[Search[List[Int]]]
}
```

Why does this last line not compile in the above example?

It fails with `ambiguous implicit values`, saying both `case1` and `case2` satisfy the condition.

Behaviour observed on scala 2.12.8 and 2.13.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala specification says:

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit parameter's type, a most specific one will be chosen using the rules of static overloading resolution.

https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html#implicit-parameters

> The relative weight of an alternative `A` over an alternative `B` is a number from 0 to 2, defined as the sum of
>
> - 1 if `A` is as specific as `B`, 0 otherwise, and
> - 1 if `A` is defined in a class or object which is derived from the class or object defining `B`, 0 otherwise.

https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution

- `case1` is defined in an object which is *derived* from the class (trait) defining `case2` but not vice versa.
- `case2` is *as specific as* `case1` but not vice versa.

So *relative weight* of `case1` over `case2` is 1+0=1 and *relative weight* of `case2` over `case1` is 0+1=1. So it's ambiguity.

```
Error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method case2 in trait LPSearch of type [M[_], A](implicit ev: App.TypeClass2[M,A])App.Search[M[A]]
 and method case1 in object Search of type [A](implicit ev: App.TypeClass1[A])App.Search[A]
 match expected type App.Search[List[Int]]
    implicitly[Search[List[Int]]]
```

In the second case there is no sense to use low-priority trait since if both implicits match expected type, `case2` is preferred when they are defined in the same object. So try

```
object Search {
  implicit def case1[A](implicit ev: TypeClass1[A]): Search[A] = null
  implicit def case2[M[_], A](implicit ev: TypeClass2[M, A]): Search[M[A]] = null
}
```

Comment: I see, that certainly explains the behaviour, thank you very much. What should I do though if I want `case1` to be preferred?

Comment: @Gesar Try to use `shapeless.LowPriority`. `object Search {
    implicit def case1[A](implicit ev: TypeClass1[A]): Search[A] = null;
    implicit def case2[M[_], A](implicit ev: TypeClass2[M, A], lowPriority: LowPriority): Search[M[A]] = null
  }` Also look at https://github.com/monix/implicitbox , https://github.com/milessabin/export-hook

Comment: @Gesar Or you can use type class [`Not`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962743/using-context-bounds-negatively-to-ensure-type-class-instance-is-absent-from-s) (there are standard `shapeless.Refute`, `implicitbox.Not`). `object Search {
    implicit def case1[A](implicit ev: TypeClass1[A]): Search[A] = null;
    implicit def case2[M[_], A](implicit ev: TypeClass2[M, A], not: Not[TypeClass1[M[A]]]): Search[M[A]] = null
  }`