# Why in-scope implicit values typed A and B are not ambiguous when B extends A?

Tags: scala, implicit, ambiguous

Why does the code in `Test2` compile even though we clearly have ambiguous implicit values?

```
object Method {
  def foo(implicit i: A): Unit = println(i.i)
}

trait A {
  val i: Int
}
class B(override val i: Int) extends A

object Test1 {
  implicit val i1: A = new A {
    val i: Int = 20
  }
}

object Test2 {
  implicit val i2: B = new B(10)
  import Test1._
  // This compiles fine and prints 10
  Method.foo
}

object Test3 {
  implicit val i2: A = new B(10)
  import Test1._
  // This does not compile, get `ambiguous implicit values`
  Method.foo
}
```

Comment: In **Test2** there is not ambiguity, because given the rules of implicit resolution. The most specific one will be chosen. And `i2` is most specific than `i1`, because **B** extends **A**. On the other hand, in **Test3** there is clear ambiguity that can't not be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Test2` there is no ambiguity. `i2` has more specific type than `i1`, so `i2` has higher priority than `i1`.

In `Test3` `i1` and `i2` have the same type `A`, so this is ambiguity.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57934397/5249621