# General way of ensuring implicit definition always has higher/lower priority

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I have a somewhat complex typeclass situation in the following format:

```
sealed trait TypeClass[S <: MyType] {
  type Out <: MyType
}

sealed trait LowPriorityTypeClass {
  // Case: OtherTypeClass is NOT defined for the input type S.
  // The output type is the same as the input type.
  implicit def default[S <: MyType]: TypeClass.Aux[S, S] = ???
}

object TypeClass extends LowPriorityTypeClass {
  type Aux[S <: MyType, O <: MyType] = TypeClass[S] { type Out = O }

  // Case: OtherTypeClass is defined for the input type S.
  // The output type is the same as in the OtherTypeClass definition.
  implicit def hasOtherTC[S <: MyType, O <: MyType](
    implicit otherTC: OtherTypeClass.Aux[S, O],
  ): TypeClass.Aux[S, O] = ???
}
```

The `default` definition was put in the `LowPriorityTypeClass` trait with the intention of having a lower priority. However, an ambiguity with `hasOtherTC` still happens for some type `S`, apparently because the declaration of `default` is more specific than the declaration of `hasOtherTC` for that type `S`.

Is there a **general** way to ensure that an implicit definition will always have a higher/lower priority than other definition? (My question is not for the specific code above.)

Let me know if posting a more complete sample code would help.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I can reproduce https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/88ec5c4c9d8ae6ccbba37898c1f66f5e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [Why is this implicit ambiguity behaviour happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933865/why-is-this-implicit-ambiguity-behaviour-happening/) including comments.

There is no sense in introducing trait `LowPriorityTypeClass` in this case because anyway implicit `default` is more specific than `hasOtherTC`.

There is no general way. You can use type classes `Not` (`shapeless.Refute`, `implicitbox.Not`) or `shapeless.LowPriority`, `implicitbox.Priority` or library https://github.com/milessabin/export-hook.

```
object TypeClass {
  type Aux[S <: MyType, O <: MyType] = TypeClass[S] {type Out = O}

  implicit def hasOtherTC[S <: MyType, O <: MyType](implicit
                                                    otherTC: OtherTypeClass.Aux[S, O]
                                                   ): TypeClass.Aux[S, O] = ???

  implicit def default[S <: MyType](implicit 
                                    noOtherTC: Refute[OtherTypeClass[S]]
                                   ): TypeClass.Aux[S, S] = ???
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmytro. Altough I had already solved my case by using a hand-made Not typeclass I was hoping there was a general way to define priorities. I though the general way was using a LowPriority trait, but I wasn't aware of the relative specificity rule :-/

Comment: @erdavila Well, there is no such thing as "priority of implicit". You can't change "priority of implicit" from 100 to 101 or 99. Just for every two candidates you have weight of the first over the second 0, 1 or 2 and weight of the second over the first 0, 1 or 2. [Using compiler internals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59349514/5249621) you can manually infer the process of implicit resolution and then you can do whatever you want but generally it's not a good practice.