# When calling a scala function with compile-time macro, how to failover smoothly when it causes compilation errors?

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-macros, dependent-type, path-dependent-type

Assuming that I intend to use the singleton/literal type feature in a scala program, this feature is provided in shapeless library in scala 2.12 (scala 2.13 supports native literal type but let's use shapeless as an example)

In shapeless, literal type is represented as a path-dependent inner type of Witness object, which can be implicitly converted from a scala literal/const:

```
import com.tribbloids.spike.BaseSpec
import shapeless.Witness

import scala.util.Random

    val w: Witness.Lt[Int] = 3

    val w2: Witness.Lt[Int] = Random.nextInt(3) // this doesn't compile
```

The second line cause compilation to throw an exception:

```
[Error] .../WitnessSuite.scala:14: Expression scala.util.Random.nextInt(3) does not evaluate to a constant or a stable reference value
one error found
```

Now, assuming that I want to write something like `Option[Witness.Lt[Int]]` that can be converted from an Int if it is a literal or not. In scala type class convention I should write something like this:

```
    trait MayHaveWitness {

      type Lit
    }

    trait MayHaveWitness_Implicits0 {

      class Some(val w: Witness.Lt[Int]) extends MayHaveWitness {

        type Lit = w.T
      }
      object None extends MayHaveWitness {

        type Lit = Nothing
      }

      implicit def fromNonLit(v: Int): None.type = None
    }

    object MayHaveWitness extends MayHaveWitness_Implicits0 {

      implicit def fromLit[T](literal: T)(implicit proof: T => Witness.Lt[Int]): MayHaveWitness.Some = new Some(literal)
    }

    val v1: MayHaveWitness = 3
    println(v1.getClass)

    val v2: MayHaveWitness = Random.nextInt(3)
    println(v2.getClass)
```

`MayHaveWitness_Implicits0` is of lower level and theoretically should be overshadowed by `fromLit` if the Witness implicit conversion is successful. Unfortunately when I execute this code all I got was:

```
class com.tribbloids.spike.shapeless_spike.WitnessSuite$MayHaveWitness_Implicits0$1$None$
class com.tribbloids.spike.shapeless_spike.WitnessSuite$MayHaveWitness_Implicits0$1$None$
```

The Witness implicit conversion never happens. My questions are:

1. why `implicit proof: T => Witness.Lt[Int]` is not a successful summoner of the following shapeless macro?

```
  implicit def apply[T](t: T): Witness.Lt[T] = macro SingletonTypeMacros.convertImpl
```

2. how do I use type classes & other scala features to implement this smooth fallback of type-level deduction? preferrably:

   - NOT using macro
   - If not possible, NOT using whitebox macro
   - If also not impossible, NOT using macro that will be discarded by dotty

Answer (score 2):

Shapeless defines [implicit **instance**](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala#L38) of type `Witness.Aux[T]`

```
implicit def apply[T]: Witness.Aux[T] = macro SingletonTypeMacros.materializeImpl[T]
```

and [implicit **conversion**](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala#L40) from type `T` to `Witness.Lt[T]`

```
implicit def apply[T](t: T): Witness.Lt[T] = macro SingletonTypeMacros.convertImpl
```

Implicit instance `Witness.Aux[T]` is resolved or not based on type `T` only (whether `T` [is a singleton type or nor](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala#L263)) like implicit instances of ordinary type classes. But  implicit conversion `T => Witness.Lt[T]` is not like ordinary implicit conversions. Ordinary implicit conversions are resolved or not based on type of a value to be conversed. But `T => Witness.Lt[T]` is resolved or not based not only on the type `T` but also on the value `t` itself (whether `t` [is constant/stable or not](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala#L289)).

If you switch on `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Ymacro-debug-lite", "-Xlog-implicits")` you'll see that in

```
val w: Witness.Lt[Int] = 3 //compiles
//Warning:scalac: performing macro expansion shapeless.this.Witness.apply[Int](3) at source-/media/data/Projects/macrosdemo213/core/src/main/scala/App114_2.scala,line-9,offset=205
//Warning:scalac: _root_.shapeless.Witness.mkWitness[Int(3)](3.asInstanceOf[Int(3)])  

val w2: Witness.Lt[Int] = Random.nextInt(3) //doesn't compile
//Warning:scalac: performing macro expansion shapeless.this.Witness.apply[Int](scala.util.Random.nextInt(3)) at source-/media/data/Projects/macrosdemo213/core/src/main/scala/App114_2.scala,line-10,offset=249
//Warning:scalac: macro expansion has failed: Expression scala.util.Random.nextInt(3) does not evaluate to a constant or a stable reference value
//Error: Expression scala.util.Random.nextInt(3) does not evaluate to a constant or a stable reference value
```

only `implicit def apply[T](t: T): Witness.Lt[T]` was checked (and worked in `w` but didn't work in `w2`).

Also in

```
val v1: MayHaveWitness = 3 // compiles but gives None
//Warning:scalac: macro expansion is delayed: shapeless.this.Witness.apply[T]
//Warning:scalac: performing macro expansion shapeless.this.Witness.apply[T]
//Warning:scalac: macro expansion has failed: Type argument T is not a singleton type
//Information: shapeless.this.Witness.apply is not a valid implicit value for Int => shapeless.Witness.Lt[Int] because:
//hasMatchingSymbol reported error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
// found   : [T]shapeless.Witness.Aux[T]
//    (which expands to)  [T]shapeless.Witness{type T = T}
// required: Int => shapeless.Witness.Lt[Int]
//    (which expands to)  Int => shapeless.Witness{type T <: Int}
//Information: App.this.MayHaveWitness.fromLit is not a valid implicit value for Int(3) => App.MayHaveWitness because:
//No implicit view available from Int => shapeless.Witness.Lt[Int].
```

and in

```
val v2: MayHaveWitness = Random.nextInt(3) // compiles but gives None
//Warning:scalac: macro expansion is delayed: shapeless.this.Witness.apply[T]
//Warning:scalac: performing macro expansion shapeless.this.Witness.apply[T]
//Warning:scalac: macro expansion has failed: Type argument T is not a singleton type
//Warning:scalac: performing macro expansion shapeless.this.Witness.apply[T]
//Information: App.this.MayHaveWitness.fromLit is not a valid implicit value for Int => App.MayHaveWitness because:
//No implicit view available from Int => shapeless.Witness.Lt[Int].
//Information: shapeless.this.Witness.apply is not a valid implicit value for Int => shapeless.Witness.Lt[Int] because:
//hasMatchingSymbol reported error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
// found   : [T]shapeless.Witness.Aux[T]
//    (which expands to)  [T]shapeless.Witness{type T = T}
// required: Int => shapeless.Witness.Lt[Int]
//    (which expands to)  Int => shapeless.Witness{type T <: Int}
//Information: App.this.MayHaveWitness.fromLit is not a valid implicit value for Int => App.MayHaveWitness because:
//No implicit view available from Int => shapeless.Witness.Lt[Int].
```

both `implicit def apply[T]: Witness.Aux[T]` and `implicit def apply[T](t: T): Witness.Lt[T]` were checked and none of them worked.

> why `implicit proof: T => Witness.Lt[Int]` is not a successful summoner of the following shapeless macro?

Compiler treats implicits of functional types `A => B` differently than implicits of other types. It can treat them as implicit conversions (views). But whether it actually treats them as conversions or just implicit instances of type `A => B` (like other types) depends on boolean [flag](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Implicits.scala#L79) `isView`.

When you do

```
val w: Witness.Lt[Int] = 3 //compiles
val w2: Witness.Lt[Int] = Random.nextInt(3) //doesn't compile
val v1: MayHaveWitness = 3 //compiles
val v2: MayHaveWitness = Random.nextInt(3) //compiles
```

`isView` is `true`. But when you do

```
implicitly[Int => Witness.Lt[Int]] //doesn't compile
implicitly[3 => Witness.Lt[Int]] //doesn't compile
implicitly[Int => MayHaveWitness] //doesn't compile
implicitly[3 => MayHaveWitness] //doesn't compile
```

or here

```
implicit def fromLit... (implicit proof: T => Witness.Lt[Int]) ...
                        ______________________________________
```

`isView` is `false`.

In simple cases existence of implicit `A => B` and implicit conversion from `A` to `B` are the same

```
class A
class B
// implicit val aToB: A => B = null // this one
implicit def aToB(a: A): B = null   // or this one
implicitly[A => B] //compiles
val b: B = new A //compiles
```

but not in our case. There is implicit conversion `3 => Witness.Lt[3]` but not an instance of this type

```
val w: Witness.Lt[3] = 3.asInstanceOf[3] //compiles

implicitly[3 => Witness.Lt[3]] // doesn't compile
//Information: shapeless.this.Witness.apply is not a valid implicit value for 3 => shapeless.Witness.Lt[3] because:
//hasMatchingSymbol reported error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
// found   : [T]shapeless.Witness.Aux[T]
//    (which expands to)  [T]shapeless.Witness{type T = T}
// required: 3 => shapeless.Witness.Lt[3]
//    (which expands to)  3 => shapeless.Witness{type T <: 3}
//Error: No implicit view available from 3 => shapeless.Witness.Lt[3].
```

so it checks `implicit def apply[T]: Witness.Aux[T]` but not `implicit def apply[T](t: T): Witness.Lt[T]`. I didn't debug implicit resolution deeply but I suspect that some type is not inferred before implicit is resolved.

There is no standard way to switch on `isView` in order to completely emulate behavior of implicit conversion while resolving `proof` in `... def fromLit... (implicit proof: T => Witness.Lt[Int]) ...`. We can switch on `isView` with macros if we use `c.inferImplicitView` rather than `c.inferImplicitValue`

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

trait ImplicitView[A, B] {
  def instance: A => B
}
object ImplicitView {
  implicit def mkImplicitView[A, B]: ImplicitView[A, B] = macro mkImplicitViewImpl[A, B]
  def mkImplicitViewImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag, B: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val tpA = weakTypeOf[A]
    val tpB = weakTypeOf[B]

    val x = TermName(c.freshName("x"))
    val conversion = c.inferImplicitView(tree = EmptyTree, from = tpA, to = tpB, silent = false)

    q"""new ImplicitView[$tpA, $tpB] {
      def instance: $tpA => $tpB = ($x: $tpA) => $conversion($x)
    }"""
  }
```

Let's replace

```
implicit def fromLit[T](literal: T)(implicit proof: T => Witness.Lt[Int]): MayHaveWitness.Some = new Some(literal)
```

with

```
implicit def fromLit[T](literal: T)(implicit proof: ImplicitView[T, Witness.Lt[Int]]): MayHaveWitness.Some = new Some(proof.instance(literal))
```

Also we have to modify

```
implicit def fromNonLit(v: Int): None.type = None
```

because it's ambiguous with `fromLit`. Reasons are similar to [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933865/why-is-this-implicit-ambiguity-behaviour-happening/). The easiest fix is to replace it with

```
implicit def fromNonLit[T](v: T): None.type = None
```

Now both

```
val v1: MayHaveWitness = 3
println(v1.getClass)

val v2: MayHaveWitness = Random.nextInt(3)
println(v2.getClass)
```

give `Some` (I suspect that's not what you wanted). That's understandable. `Random.nextInt(3)` is `Int`. And we were resolving `MayHaveWitness` based only on types. And there is implicit conversion `Int => Witness.Lt[Int]`. So it's `Some`.

**So it seems if we want `v1` to give `Some` and `v2` to give `None` then we can't do that based only on types. So approach with type classes will not work and we'll have to use macros.**

```
trait MayHaveWitness {
  type Lit
}

object MayHaveWitness  {
  class Some(val w: Witness.Lt[Int]) extends MayHaveWitness {
    type Lit = w.T
  }
  object None extends MayHaveWitness {
    type Lit = Nothing
  }

  implicit def fromLit[T](literal: T): MayHaveWitness = macro fromLitImpl[T]
  def fromLitImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context)(literal: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val conversion = c.inferImplicitView(tree = literal, from = weakTypeOf[T], to = typeOf[Witness.Lt[Int]], silent = false)
    util.Try(c.typecheck(q"new MayHaveWitness.Some($conversion($literal))"))
      .getOrElse(q"MayHaveWitness.None")
  }
}
```

Here we replaced `(implicit proof: T => Witness.Lt[Int])` with `c.inferImplicitView...` and we explored not only type of `literal` but also `literal` itself.

Now in

```
val v1: MayHaveWitness = 3
println(v1.getClass)

val v2: MayHaveWitness = Random.nextInt(3)
println(v2.getClass)
```

`v1` gves `Some` and `v2` gives `None`.

If you make `fromLit` blackbox it will still work but will return `MayHaveWitness` instead of `MayHaveWitness.Some` and `MayHaveWitness.None`.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of experiments, big fan now :)
I'll wait for a few days before accepting it, hoping that a blackbox only method could be possible (otherwise it will be lost in Dotty). Theoretically, since implicit summoning algorithm is just a recursive tree search, it should be easy to tell compiler to backtrack instead of failing immediately

Comment: @tribbloid Normally implicit resolution is based on types. But `3` (it's just `3`, not even `3.narrow`) and `Random.nextInt(3)` have the same type `Int`. So it's not just ordinary implicit resolution, it's implicit resolution with type inference interferred by white macros.

Comment: @tribbloid Also implicit resolution is not just tree search. It interacts with type inference (in both directions). So you're searching through a tree where node types are not completely inferred and become inferred more during resolution. So the question is not only in backtracking but also whether it should be done.

Comment: One more example of implicit conversions based not on types https://gitter.im/fthomas/refined?at=5f883e1c270d004bcfcb219e