# Scala Kleisli throws an error in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, functional-programming, implicit, kleisli

trying to implement Kleisli category for a made-up Partial type in Scala (reading Bartosz Milewski's "category theory for programmers", that's exersize for chapter 4)

```scala
object Kleisli {
  type Partial[A, B] = A => Option[B]

  implicit class KleisliOps[A, B](f1: Partial[A, B]) {

    def >=>[C](f2: Partial[B, C]): Partial[A, C] =
      (x: A) =>
        for {
          y <- f1(x)
          z <- f2(y)
        } yield z

    def identity(f: Partial[A, B]): Partial[A, B] = x => f(x)

  }

  val safeRecip: Partial[Double, Double] = {
    case 0d => None
    case x => Some(1d / x)
  }

  val safeRoot: Partial[Double, Double] = {
    case x if x < 0 => None
    case x => Some(Math.sqrt(x))
  }
  
  val safeRootRecip: Partial[Double, Double] = safeRoot.>=>(safeRecip) 
  
  safeRootRecip(1d)
  safeRootRecip(10d)
  safeRootRecip(0d)
}
```

IDE (IntelliJ) shows no errors, but when I run this snippet, I get:

```
Error:(27, 57) value >=> is not a member of $line5.$read.$iw.$iw.Kleisli.Partial[Double,Double]
val safeRootRecip: Partial[Double, Double] = safeRoot.>=>(safeRecip)
```

Defining `>=>` outside of implicit class works fine. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**@sinanspd** was right. In Dotty the code seems to compile:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/n17APWgMQkWqy93ct2cghw

Manually resolved

```
val safeRootRecip: Partial[Double, Double] = KleisliOps(safeRoot).>=>(safeRecip)
```

compiles but compiler doesn't find this conversion itself

```
Information: KleisliOps{<null>} is not a valid implicit value 
  for App.safeRoot.type => ?{def >=> : ?} because:
type mismatch;
 found   : App.safeRoot.type (with underlying type App.Partial[Double,Double])
 required: App.Partial[A,Double]
    (which expands to)  A => Option[Double]
  val safeRootRecip: Partial[Double, Double] = safeRoot.>=>(safeRecip)
```

It seems type parameter `A` is not inferred.

(By the way, here Martin Odersky explains why presence of implicit conversions in language makes type inference worse: https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/can-we-wean-scala-off-implicit-conversions/4388)

Try to make `Partial` covariant with respect to `B` and (especially) contravariant with respect to `A` (similarly to `A => Option[B]` being covariant with respect to `B` and contravariant with respect to `A`)

```
type Partial[-A, +B] = A => Option[B]
```

Then the code seems to compile.

Another workaround is to replace implicit conversions (`X => Y`, `KleisliOps`) with a type class (`MyTransform`) and implicit conversion (`myConversion`) defined in terms of this type class ([sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630439/in-scala-are-there-any-condition-where-implicit-view-wont-be-able-to-propagate/) this helps with implicit conversions)

```
trait MyTransform[X, Y] {
  def transform(x: X): Y
}
implicit def myConversion[X, Y](x: X)(implicit mt: MyTransform[X, Y]): Y = 
  mt.transform(x)

type Partial[A, B] = A => Option[B]

implicit def partialToKleisliOps[A, B]: MyTransform[Partial[A, B], KleisliOps[A, B]] = 
  f1 => new KleisliOps(f1)
class KleisliOps[A, B](f1: Partial[A, B]) {    
  def >=>[C](f2: Partial[B, C]): Partial[A, C] =
    (x: A) =>
      for {
        y <- f1(x)
        z <- f2(y)
      } yield z

  def identity(f: Partial[A, B]): Partial[A, B] = x => f(x)
}
```

Comment: Small typo: "(especially) contravariant with respect to B" should say "A" instead.