# Implicit view not working - is my implicit def to blame?

Tags: scala, generics, implicit-conversion, typeclass, implicit

I'm having some trouble with an implicit view. I suspect this is quite trivial and may have some embarassingly easy answer. I have a situation like this, along with (obviously, unsuccessful) attempts to debug it:

```
abstract class StoresNumeric[A, T: Numeric] {
  def getNum(self: A): T
}
object StoresNumericSyntax {
  implicit class StoresNumericOps[A, T: Numeric](value: A) {
    def getNum(implicit sn: StoresNumeric[A, T]): T = sn.getNum(value)
  }
}
case class ANumber[T: Numeric](
  num: T
)
implicit def aNumberStoresNumeric[T: Numeric] = 
  new StoresNumeric[ANumber[T], T] {
    def getNum(self: ANumber[T]): T = self.num
  }
val a = ANumber[Int](3)
// 1. Works fine, so explicit conversion possible
aNumberStoresNumeric[Int].getNum(a) 
// 2. Works fine, so implicit conversion possible
implicitly[StoresNumeric[ANumber[Int], Int]].getNum(a) 
// 3. Doesn't work, so implicit conversion not working
println(implicitly[ANumber[Int] => StoresNumeric[ANumber[Int], Int]]) // no implicit view available...
// 4. The holy grail. Doesn't work, for the same reason as above, plus possibly other
a.getNum
```

I think the issue here is my `implicit def`, or more accurately my lack of understanding about `implicit def` is actually meant to work. I'm not sure what role the generics play - should the first generic argument be used to represent the type I would actually like converted, or is it OK as it is?

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: It would be better to use a [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) instead - also, make your ops class a [**value class**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) to avoid allocation.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - thanks - if I understand you correctly, you mean creating a typeclass from a trait rather than an abstract class? If so, this is a simplified example, but I think it does need to be an abstract class, in order to be able to constrain the generic parameters with context bounds. A more detailed example of something similar is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769737/typeclass-constraint-in-typeclass-generic

Comment: I meant use a **typeclass** instead of an **implicit conversion**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - apologies but it's not clear to me what you mean - the implicit conversion is there as a means of creating an instance of the StoresNumeric typeclass - do you mean to use another typeclass?
I have just tried switching to a value class, but at first glance this only seems to work for  concrete typeclasses, ie those with no additional generic parameters.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood your question. You are already using a **typeclass**. - You only need to import the syntax `import StoresNumericSyntax._` before calling `a.getNum`  - Also, try to reformulate your syntax like this: `implicit class StoresNumericOps[A](private val value: A) extends AnyVal {` and then the method like this: `def getNum[T](implicit sn: StoresNumeric[A, T])`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - thanks very much - it seems that switching to the value class method has solved both the example problem and its real-world counterpart. It appears to expand the scope in which the typeclass instance is available?
One thing which still silghtly puzzles me is that the implicit conversion (number 3 in my example) still doesn't work - not that it needs to, that was just for debugging.
Anyway if you'd like to propose what you said as an answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: @Chrisper For me the fix proposed by LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez still doesn't work (without `import Numeric.IntIsIntegral`) https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TaMo4kW7QJKX1jzOKVFLkg What version of Scala do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly (#3),

```
implicitly[ANumber[Int] => StoresNumeric[ANumber[Int], Int]]
```

is wrong. You do not define an implicit conversion from a data type to a type class, you define an implicit conversion from a data type to an implicit class introducing extension method. So it should be

```
implicitly[ANumber[Int] => StoresNumericSyntax.StoresNumericOps[ANumber[Int], Int]]
```

and it compiles.

*Be prepared that `implicitly[A => B]` not always checks that an implicit conversion from `A` to `B` exists.* `*` (see below)

Secondly (#4), when you use extension method (`a.getNum`) you should import syntax object:

```
import StoresNumericSyntax._
(a: StoresNumericOps[ANumber[Int], Int]).getNum
```

compiles while

```
import StoresNumericSyntax._
a.getNum
```

produces (with `scalacOptions += "-Xlog-implicits"` switched on)

```
 Warning:
StoresNumericOps is not a valid implicit value for App.a.type => ?{def getNum: ?} because:
ambiguous implicit values:
 both object BigIntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.BigIntIsIntegral.type
 and object IntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral.type
 match expected type Numeric[T]
```

If you import `IntIsIntegral` you'll add this implicit to the local scope (before that it was in the implicit scope only), so you'll make its "priority" "higher" than the one of `BigIntIsIntegral`. Try

```
import StoresNumericSyntax._
import Numeric.IntIsIntegral
a.getNum
```

It compiles.

Scala 2.13.3.

See also how to debug implicits (at compile time): [In scala 2 or 3, is it possible to debug implicit resolution process in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348301/in-scala-2-or-3-is-it-possible-to-debug-implicit-resolution-process-in-runtime)

---

`*` For example if you modify the implicit class as **@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez** advised in comments

```
object StoresNumericSyntax {
  implicit class StoresNumericOps[A](private val value: A) extends AnyVal {
    def getNum[T: Numeric](implicit sn: StoresNumeric[A, T]): T = sn.getNum(value)
  }
}
```

then

```
import StoresNumericSyntax._
implicitly[ANumber[Int] => StoresNumericOps[ANumber[Int]]]
```

doesn't compile

```
 Warning:
StoresNumericOps is not a valid implicit value for ANumber[Int] => StoresNumericSyntax.StoresNumericOps[ANumber[Int]] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: type mismatch;
 found   : StoresNumericSyntax.StoresNumericOps.type
 required: ANumber[Int] => StoresNumericSyntax.StoresNumericOps[App393.ANumber[Int]]
```

while manually resolved

```
implicitly[ANumber[Int] => StoresNumericOps[ANumber[Int]]](new StoresNumericOps(_))
```

compiles and

```
import StoresNumericSyntax._
a: StoresNumericOps[ANumber[Int]]
```

compiles too.

But if I remove `extends AnyVal`

```
object StoresNumericSyntax {
  implicit class StoresNumericOps[A](private val value: A) /*extends AnyVal*/ {
    def getNum[T: Numeric](implicit sn: StoresNumeric[A, T]): T = sn.getNum(value)
  }
}
```

then

```
import StoresNumericSyntax._
implicitly[ANumber[Int] => StoresNumericOps[ANumber[Int]]]
```

compiles.

Also if I split the implicit class into a class + an implicit conversion

```
object StoresNumericSyntax {
  /*implicit*/ class StoresNumericOps[A](private val value: A) extends AnyVal {
    def getNum[T: Numeric](implicit sn: StoresNumeric[A, T]): T = sn.getNum(value)
  }

  implicit def toStoresNumericOps[A](value: A): StoresNumericOps[A] =
    new StoresNumericOps(value)
}
```

then

```
import StoresNumericSyntax._
implicitly[ANumber[Int] => StoresNumericOps[ANumber[Int]]]
```

compiles.

Why `implicitly[A => B]` is not the same as `val x: B = ??? : A` is expained here:

[In scala, are there any condition where implicit view won't be able to propagate to other implicit function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630439/in-scala-are-there-any-condition-where-implicit-view-wont-be-able-to-propagate)

[When calling a scala function with compile-time macro, how to failover smoothly when it causes compilation errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205940/when-calling-a-scala-function-with-compile-time-macro-how-to-failover-smoothly)

[Scala Kleisli throws an error in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751493/scala-kleisli-throws-an-error-in-intellij)

[What are the hidden rules regarding the type inference in resolution of implicit conversions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002466/what-are-the-hidden-rules-regarding-the-type-inference-in-resolution-of-implicit)

[Scala: `ambigious implicit values` but the right value is not event found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697952/scala-ambigious-implicit-values-but-the-right-value-is-not-event-found/)

The impact of presence/absence of `extends AnyVal` on implicit resolution can be a bug but difference between implicit instance (`implicitly[A => B]`) and implicit conversion (`val x: B = ??? : A`) is more or less intentional (different strategies of type inference, resolving type parameters are used).

Comment: Hi Dmytro, thanks as ever for these great answers. I was being a bit hasty yesterday when I said it was all fixed - using a value class fixed my real-world example but not the simplified one above. I'm using 2.13.2 and I get the same results as you - importing `IntIsIntegral` makes `a.getNum` work, and using a non-value class for the implicit view and importing `StoresNumericSyntax` makes the `implicitly[A => B]` line work. It sounds like you're less of a fan of the `extends Anyval` approach that Luis mentioned?

Comment: I was slightly surprised that it was the ambiguity about implicits that was causing `a.getNum` not to work - you might think that the compiler could show a more helpful error message than `value getNum is not a member of` ... since it could presumably tell you that there is a conflict with implicits occurring.

Comment: @Chrisper *"compiler could show a more helpful error message"* But it does provide helpful message as a warning if you switch `-Xlog-implicits` on. *"It sounds like you're less of a fan of the `extends Anyval`"* Value classes are ok, it's an optimization to avoid runtime overhead, although they have many limitations https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html (see also https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype), they are not supposed to interfere with implicit resolution.