# Creating a type-sensitive function without changing the parent trait or case classes

Tags: scala, class, extension-methods, implicit, implicit-class

Suppose I have two classes, `Person` and `Business`, that are extended by the trait `Entity`.

```
trait Entity
case class Person(name: String) extends Entity
case class Business(id: String) extends Entity
```

Assuming I cannot change `Entity`, `Person` and `Business` (they are in a different file and not to be changed) how can I define a function, say a `printEntity`, that prints the field `name` or `id`, depending on the entity? For example, given instances of `Person` and `Business`, how can I do something like this:

```
object Main extends App {
  val person1: Person = Person("Aaaa Bbbb")
  val business1: Business = Business("0001")
  
  // How can I do something like this?
  person1.printEntity // would call a function that executes println(id)
  business1.printEntity // would call a function that executes println(name)
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated! Sorry for the lack of context, I am still learning!

Comment: Scala 2 https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html Scala 3 https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done via so called ["extension methods"](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/implicit-extension-methods-functions-scala-2-3-dotty/). In scala 2 this is achieved using implicit wrapper class:

```scala
trait Entity
case class Person(name: String) extends Entity
case class Business(id: String) extends Entity

implicit class PersonWrapper(val p: Person) extends AnyVal {
  def printEntity(): Unit = {
    println(p.name)
  }
}

implicit class BusinessWrapper(val b: Business) extends AnyVal {
  def printEntity(): Unit = {
    println(b.id)
  }
}

val person1: Person = Person("Aaaa Bbbb")
val business1: Business = Business("0001")

person1.printEntity()
business1.printEntity()

// prints:
//Aaaa Bbbb
//0001
```

Note, `x.printEntity` can be called without parentheses, but, by convention, methods with `Unit` result type and side effects should be called with explicit empty parentheses.

---

UPD: As @DmytroMitin pointed out, you should [extend implicit wrapper classes from `AnyVal`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#extension-methods). This allows the compiler to avoid actually allocating wrapper class instances at runtime, improving performance.

Comment: You could make the implicit classes extend `AnyVal` https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html

Comment: @DmytroMitin, thank you for the reminder, I've updated my answer.

Comment: This shouldn't be added to your answer (it's already ok, I upvoted) but just for the record there are exotic cases when an ordinary class + an implicit conversion can be better than the corresponding  implicit class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63964610/implicit-view-not-working-is-my-implicit-def-to-blame/ :) I haven't checked in the current Scala 2.13.6. Surely normally that's not the case.