# In Scala 2/3, why can't unboxing or view bounds be chained (as in OCaml), and how to fix/circumvent it?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, scala-3, view-bound

Considering the following example, derived from the official manual of Scala 3 on Context Abstractions:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/incompat-contextual-abstractions.html#view-bounds

```scala
object ViewBound {

  trait Boxed[T] {
    def v: T
  }

  object Boxed {

    implicit def unbox[T, R](
        boxed: Boxed[T]
    )(
        implicit
        more: T => R
    ): R = more(boxed.v)
  }

  case class B0(v: String) extends Boxed[String]
  case class B1(v: B0) extends Boxed[B0]
  case class B2(v: B1) extends Boxed[B1]

  val b2 = B2(B1(B0("a")))

  val ab = b2.concat("b")
}
```

Theoretically, the view bound `unbox` should be used repeatedly until the function `concat` is found, in each iteration `unbox` is a valid candidate in scope. In practice, the compiler will report the following error (tested in Scala 3.4.2-snapshot build):

```
[Error] /home/peng/git/dottyspike/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/dotty/ViewBound.scala:25:15: value concat is not a member of com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.B2.
An extension method was tried, but could not be fully constructed:

    com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Boxed.unbox[
      com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.B1,
      com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.B1](
      com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.b2)(
      $conforms[com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.B1])
```

What's the cause of this behaviour and how to make it work?

**UPDATE 1**: just tried the typeclass idea and Nope, still doesn't work:

```scala
  object V2 {

    trait Boxed[T] {
      def self: T
    }

    object Boxed {

      trait ViewBound[S, R] extends (S => R) {}

      implicit def unbox1[T]: ViewBound[Boxed[T], T] = v => v.self

      implicit def unboxMore[T, R](
          implicit
          more: ViewBound[T, R]
      ): ViewBound[Boxed[T], R] = v => more(v.self)

      implicit def convert[T, R](v: Boxed[T])(
          implicit
          unbox: ViewBound[Boxed[T], R]
      ): R = unbox(v)
    }

    case class B0(self: String) extends Boxed[String]
    val b0 = B0("a")
    b0.concat("b")

    case class B1(self: B0) extends Boxed[B0]
    val b1 = B1(B0("a"))
    b1.concat("b")

    case class B2(self: B1) extends Boxed[B1]
    val b2 = B2(B1(B0("a")))
    b2.concat("b")
  }
```

```
[Error] /home/peng/git/dottyspike/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/dotty/ViewBound.scala:27:17: value concat is not a member of com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Failed.B2.
An extension method was tried, but could not be fully constructed:

    com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Failed.Boxed.unbox[
      com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Failed.B1,
      com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Failed.B1](
      com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Failed.b2)(
      $conforms[com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Failed.B1])
[Error] /home/peng/git/dottyspike/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/dotty/ViewBound.scala:59:8: value concat is not a member of com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Success.B1.
An extension method was tried, but could not be fully constructed:

    com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Success.Boxed.convert[
      com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Success.B0,
      com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Success.B0](
      com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Success.b1)(
      com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Success.Boxed.unbox1[
        com.tribbloids.spike.dotty.ViewBound.Success.B0]
    )
```

Comment: Allowing chains of implicit conversions would be a very bad idea. I won't even touch on how most of the time anyone reading the code would blame the writer. The performance of the compiler would be magnitude of orders slower since it would be motivated to apply and apply and apply implicit conversions until any type mismatch is fixed. - Rather, I would suggest redesigning the code using a typeclass that would control this deep search and be explicit about the desire to unbox.

Comment: well implicit conversion is itself a typeclass (Of function type) that can be recursively summoned (as long as each time it yields a different root type to avoid a diverging implicit search error). There will be no difference

Comment: But thanks a lot for the idea! I'll start experimenting on a ViewBound typeclass-based solution & try to post my answer. If you already have examples, feel free to post it!

Comment: IMHO the chains of implicit conversions can always be expanded by the IDE when others are reading it. Macro & staging etc on the other hand ...

Comment: I started to suspect that it is a bug caused by misidentified diverging implicit search, the capability is clearly there: https://gist.github.com/SethTisue/5ab846d1639af0e75e86ca19002689dc

Comment: I believe it's not a bug: implicit search has to "converge" in a way: each next step should be deterministic from the previous one, there is no backtracking (I mean, there is one implicit requires another and compiler checks if that another can be found, but even then it kinda already committed to some types), it never "searches whole solution space". While it resembles prolog, it's a prolog with tons of `!` everywhere. Otherwise every other library would turn into several-hour-long compile-time riddle-bruteforce. It's a conscious design decision, take it or leave it.

Comment: To clarify: every attempt like: I have an input type I, I have an output type O, can you find a path of values like I -> M1, M1 -> M2, M2 -> ... MN, MN -> O is going to fail. The only way to make it succeed is using path-dependent types (usually with Aux-pattern) so that you encode: "if this type is I, the path-dependent sth.Out is M1", "if this type is M1, then sth.Out is M2" etc. But then you are not "searching through a whole solution space", you are basically searching if there is a path in a directed tree between 2 nodes, starting at one node and ending at another.

Comment: (citing Kotlin document) "the compiler will generate all the methods of Base that forward to b", in Scala, these method signatures can be part of the metadata, and it happens once. Also, remember that Kotlin is a much faster compiler

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html#overriding-a-member-of-an-interface-implemented-by-delegation

Comment: OCaml also has a faster compiler

Answer (score 1):

You could use a type class + extension method rather than implicit conversions

```scala
trait Unbox[-A, +B] {
  def apply(a: A): B
}
object Unbox {
  implicit def recurse[A, B](implicit u: Unbox[A, B]): Unbox[Boxed[A], B] = boxed => u(boxed.v)
  implicit def base[A]: Unbox[Boxed[A], A] = _.v
}

implicit class BoxedOps[T](val boxed: T) extends AnyVal {
  def concat(s: String)(implicit u: Unbox[T, String]): String = u(boxed).concat(s)
}
```

```scala
case class B0(v: String) extends Boxed[String]
case class B1(v: B0) extends Boxed[B0]
case class B2(v: B1) extends Boxed[B1]

val b0 = B0("a")
val b1 = B1(b0)
val b2 = B2(b1)

b0.concat("b") //ab
b1.concat("b") //ab
b2.concat("b") //ab
```

It can be dangerous to formulate your logic in terms of implicit conversions. They are tricky. They are resolved/typechecked differently than implicits of non-functional types.

The problem with inductive definitions

```scala
implicit def foo[A, B]...(implicit x: X[A, B])...
```

is to decide what to prefer: to define the implicit for arbitrary `A`, `B` (i.e. to postpone type inference, lazy strategy) or to infer e.g. `B` based on `A` (i.e. to make type inference now, eager strategy). For implicit conversions (`isView == true`) the eager strategy is preferred, for all other non-functional types (`isView == false`) the lazy one is preferred

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/232521f418c1e2c535d3630b0a5b3972a06bbd4e/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Implicits.scala#L846-L866

```scala
val itree2 = if (!isView) fallback else pt match {
  case Function1(arg1, arg2) =>
    typed1(
      atPos(itree0.pos)(Apply(itree1, Ident(nme.argument).setType(approximate(arg1)) :: Nil)),
      EXPRmode,
      approximate(arg2)
    ) match {
      // try to infer implicit parameters immediately in order to:
      //   1) guide type inference for implicit views
      //   2) discard ineligible views right away instead of risking spurious ambiguous implicits
      //
      // this is an improvement of the state of the art that brings consistency to implicit resolution rules
      // (and also helps fundep materialization to be applicable to implicit views)
      //
      // there's one caveat though. we need to turn this behavior off for scaladoc
      // because scaladoc usually doesn't know the entire story
      // and is just interested in views that are potentially applicable
      // for instance, if we have `class C[T]` and `implicit def conv[T: Numeric](c: C[T]) = ???`
      // then Scaladoc will give us something of type `C[T]`, and it would like to know
      // that `conv` is potentially available under such and such conditions
      case tree if isImplicitMethodType(tree.tpe) && !isScaladoc =>
        applyImplicitArgs(tree)
```

Suppose a typeclass has any instances

```scala
trait TC[A, B] 
implicit def mkTC[A, B]: TC[A, B] = null
```

then an instance is found: `implicitly[TC[Int, String]]`, but implicit conversion

```scala
implicit def conversion[A, B](a: A)(implicit tc: TC[A, B]): B = ???
```

will not work: `val s: String = 1 // error`

[Scala: `ambigious implicit values` but the right value is not event found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697952/scala-ambigious-implicit-values-but-the-right-value-is-not-event-found)

[What are the hidden rules regarding the type inference in resolution of implicit conversions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002466/what-are-the-hidden-rules-regarding-the-type-inference-in-resolution-of-implicit)

[In scala, are there any condition where implicit view won't be able to propagate to other implicit function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630439/in-scala-are-there-any-condition-where-implicit-view-wont-be-able-to-propagate)

[When calling a scala function with compile-time macro, how to failover smoothly when it causes compilation errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205940/when-calling-a-scala-function-with-compile-time-macro-how-to-failover-smoothly)

[Scala Kleisli throws an error in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751493/scala-kleisli-throws-an-error-in-intellij)

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/can-we-wean-scala-off-implicit-conversions/4388

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/proposed-changes-and-restrictions-for-implicit-conversions/4923

[How can I chain implicits in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332801/how-can-i-chain-implicits-in-scala/)

Comment: Thank you professor, the example works in both V2 & V3. But `concat` still has be manually defined (as in `export concat`), ideally many methods of String should all become visible after unboxing (as in wildcard export https://users.scala-lang.org/t/wildcard-export-and-export-omitter-in-scala-3/9202)